# Terms similar to Sibilant

Tags: terminology, phonology

Is there a term, similar to sibilance with respect to sh, s, etc. that corresponds to words with respect to a and u(ah)? And also for the rest of the syllables and alphabets?

Comment: @sumelic Aren't certain words sibilant, because they have the sounds ss, or sh in them? Since uh and ah are similar, I mean to ask if there exists a term for words that are dominated by these sounds, just like sibilant is for s.

Comment: "Sibilant" refers to a class of similar sounds including "s", "sh", "z". Words that contain a lot of these sounds may be called "sibilant" also. But can you please give an example of a word you think is dominated by the sounds "uh" and "ah"?

Comment: @sumelic acrobatic, arrogance, unapologetic?

Comment: I see. Vowels like this are called "low vowels" (in opposition to vowels like the "ee" in "feet" or the "oo" in "boot"). I don't know of a single term for words that have a high percentage of low vowels.

Comment: Are you looking for the category of terms which includes *sibilants*, *plosives*, *frictives*, *nasals*, etc? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manner_of_articulation

Comment: @DanBron Yes, I'd gone through similar articles, but hadn't found anything specific about sounds that are ah, and uh. This is pretty clear. Thanks.

Comment: I find your question unclear. What exactly would you like to know? Whether there is a term for sounds like a and u? See sumelic's comment.

Comment: Or what other classificatory terms there are for sounds? Then this question is way too broad; there are dozens of them. I would recommend you having a look at an introductory phonology textbook; there you will find discussions of different sond classes w.r.t. certain features providing an explanation *why* these classifications are so, e.g what the parameters are that can be used to distinguish consonants as opposed to vowels. This will be way more helpful than "Please list me all kinds of sound classes there are".

Comment: @lemontree I did.

Comment: @lemontree My question wasn't for anyone to list all of them anyway. Just specifically, the uh sounds. The answersumeric provided was quite enough. But thanks. :)

Comment: @Ardy If it's just about the last part, then you should remove the last sentence. which is what caused the question to become unclear/too broad in my opinion. If you can narrow your question down this way, I'll retract my downvote and my closevote - but I didn't want to edit because I'm not exactly sure just removing the last sentence is what you want.

Comment: Why would you want such a term? Do words like unapologetic and acrobatic form a natural class? I don't think so. The vowels at the start of those words might, but you should consult a vowel chart to find out the minimal set of features that give you the class. [open] might suffice, but this would also give you /o/ initial words like 'awkward'. Maybe [open,anterior]? Again though, why? 'Sibilant' isn't used to refer to s/sh- initial words, really.